# Is the date value returned by the facebook API(s) in GMT format?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

Is the date value returned by the facebook API(s) in GMT format? So if I query for messages containing a certain word (e.g. 'sports') I try to search for all messages b/w 2 dates (in my local timezone), so how am I supposed to interpret the values returned by the search? Would it be GMT or my local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Facebook Developer page:

> All date fields are returned as ISO-8601 formatted strings. You can optionally override the date format by specifying a "date_format" query parameter. The accepted format strings are identical to those accepted by the php date function. For example, https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed?date_format=U returns the Platform page's feed, with unixtime-formatted dates.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/